# Coefficient of degree $-1$ in $df/f$

Tags: derivatives, power-series

Let $f=\sum_{i\ge m} a^i t^t$ (for  $m\in \mathbb Z$) a formal Laurent power series and consider its formal differential $df$. What is the coefficient of degree $-1$ of the differential form $\frac{df}{f}$? Do we have an explicit expression?

Answer (score 0):

Since $\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{f} = \mathrm{d} \log(f)$, you can factor out the overall factor of $t$:

$$ \log \left( \sum_{i \geq m} a^i t^i \right)
= m \log(t) + \log \left( \sum_{i \geq 0} a^{i+m} t^{i} \right) $$

The second term only has coefficients in nonnegative degree, and $\mathrm{d}\log(t) = \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{t}$.

If you're uncomfortable with taking logarithms of formal power series, you can view the above as inspirational; once you know what the result "should" be you can prove it without invoking logarithms.

For example, you can show by the product rule that

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}(fg)}{fg} = \frac{\mathrm{d}f}{f} + \frac{\mathrm{d}g}{g} $$

which lets you  mimic the proof sketch above.

Comment: what is the logarithm of a formal power series?

Comment: @manifold: The starting point I'm most familiar with is to define $\log(1 + a_1 t + \ldots)$ by plugging in $x = a_1 t + \ldots$ into the power series for $\log(1+x)$. The result converges, thus giving a well-defined function for power series of the form above. Another definition idea is to define $\log(f)$ as a formal antiderivative of $\frac{f'}{f}$. But as I say in my answer, you don't *need* to use the logarithm in the final draft of your calculation/proof.

Comment: (I'm assuming characteristic zero; there are some issues with defining the logarithm in positive characteristic due to denominators in the power series, but it's still good inspiration)

Comment: Some sources will even still define $\mathrm{d}\log(f)$ (as being equal to $\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{f}$) even if they don't define $\log(f)$.